# What/Why does this print?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I ran into this old blog post : https://blog.kevmod.com/2014/06/

```py
X = 0
Y = 0
def wrapper():
    X = 1
    Y = 1
    class C(object):
        print X, Y # <- what happens at this line?
        X = 2
wrapper()
```

Apparently this prints  `"0,1"`!!!!

While there was a pretty thorough explanation as to why it prints it:

"The technical details are that there are a number of different opcodes that Python can use to look up names; in a function scope locals are looked up with LOAD_FAST, but in a classdef they are looked up with LOAD_NAME, which does not check any parent scopes and just skips to the global scope. Non-locals in classdefs are looked up with either LOAD_NAME or LOAD_DEREF, the latter of which will check enclosing scopes."

What I didn't understand is why it prints at all? How is printing inside a declaration even valid?

Comment: You could try and hoist `class C` outside of the function and it will still `print`.

Comment: I think you are confused because you have experience with compiled languages like C, C++, or Java. Python is a dynamic interpreted language. So when you define a class, it literally interprets every line in its definition and executes it. You can run your entire program inside a class definition and it would still be valid python because thats just it works.

Comment: Python,being an interpreted language, does not distinguish between declaration and execution. Everything happens at runtime and code is interpreted as encountered.

Comment: Thanks all, I have been developing compiled code so much I forgot the basics :(

Comment: @sureshvv That makes it sound like *every* interpreted language works that way, which is not the case. That class bodies are just regular imperative code is a peculiarity of Python.